# Who (or what) is Unbreakable?

Tags: unbreakable-trilogy, unbreakable

In the film *[Unbreakable](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0217869/)* we meet David, a man who evidently possesses a wide range of superpowers including the ability to withstand impacts. He is **quite literally unbreakable.**

By comparison, the film's deuteragonist, Elijah *appears* very breakable indeed (having suffered multiple fractures over his lifetime) but demonstrates an **indomitable will to succeed** in his self-assigned task of locating and training a superhero.

Does the film's title refer to David or Elijah or something else entirely?

Comment: Oh, random downvoter, you do make me smile.

Comment: "random downvoter" IKR?! Haters gonna hate.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## The link between hero and villain is unbreakable.

I agree that "unbreakable" refers to David's ability to withstand and survive powerful impacts, that it provides a contrast to Elijah's physical vulnerability, and that it also refers to Elijah's indomitable will to succeed.

But I also always believed, in keeping with the film's view that comic books contain ancient truths about the human condition, that it refers to the **unbreakable link between hero and nemesis — one defines the other**.

> **ELIJAH:** Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero. And most times they're friends, like you and me! I should've known way back when... You know why, David? Because of the kids. They called me Mr Glass.

[image]

M. Night Shyamalan himself described the core idea of the film as follows:

> Good cannot exist without evil and evil cannot exist without good.

(M. Night Shyamalan et. al, *The Making of Unbreakable*, Walt Disney Home Entertainment, 2001)

Comment: Great answer. I hadn't thought of that at all.

Comment: Really nice answer